# Databse tables IBM Process App and tasks or services designed within the app

Tags: ibm-bpm

Process App information is stored in LSW_PROJECT table
Human services and other "tasks" are designed in Process Designer to the Process App. I believe these are stored in LSW_PROCESS and LSW_PROCESS_ITEM.

How do I make a query associating a Process App to the services included in that App?

What is the significance of LSW_TASK table?

Is there any documentation which describe the tables used in IBM BPM ?

Answer (score 0):

Querying the product database tables is not a supported method in IBM BPM. The database schema is not documented in the [BPM knowledge center](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSFPJS_8.5.5/com.ibm.wbpm.main.doc/kc-homepage-bpm.html). There are [REST API](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSFPJS_8.5.5/com.ibm.wbpm.ref.doc/rest/bpmrest/rest_bpm_wle.htm?cp=SSFPJS_8.5.5&lang=en) and [Java Script API](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSFPJS_8.5.5/com.ibm.wbpm.ref.doc/ae/doc/JSAPI.html?lang=en) method to obtain information about the projects (which are stored in `LSW_PROJECT`).  For the JS API, you could go through all process apps with the `getAllProcessApps` or the REST API with [GET /rest/bpm/wle/v1/processApps](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSFPJS_8.5.5/com.ibm.wbpm.ref.doc/rest/bpmrest/rest_bpm_wle_v1_processapps_get.htm?cp=SSFPJS_8.5.5&lang=en)

The `LSW_TASK` table holds information about the tasks which people (users) or the system processes. These are created for each activity on a BPD diagram. These are then deleted with the [BPDProcessInstanceCleanup](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSFPJS_8.5.5/com.ibm.wbpm.ref.doc/topics/rref_BPMProcessInstancesCleanup.html?lang=en) command is run.

If you describe your what problem you are trying to solve, I can direct you to specific resources that may already exist.

Comment: Further if you are on a newer release you could use https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SS964W/com.ibm.wbpm.ref.doc/topics/rref_bpmtaskscleanup.html to cleanup tasks. Starting with 8.5.7.0 you could use the BPMProcessInstancesPurge command to delete tasks and processes.